# Why was my application still rejected after excluding files from iCloud backup using this code?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud

I have added the following code to exclude files from iCloud backup, but my application was still rejected:

```
   - (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
    if (&NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey == nil) { // iOS <= 5.0.1
        const char* filePath = [[URL path] fileSystemRepresentation];

        const char* attrName = "com.apple.MobileBackup";
        u_int8_t attrValue = 1;

        int result = setxattr(filePath, attrName, &attrValue, sizeof(attrValue), 0, 0);
        return result == 0;
    } else { // iOS >= 5.1


        NSLog(@"%d",[URL setResourceValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error:nil]);
        return [URL setResourceValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error:nil];
    }
}
```

and I passed the below url in as an NSURL, in the case of the Simulator:

> file:///Users/TEST/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.1/Applications/62854BAB-AB51-4771-895F-28C61983A7AC/Documents/MyFolder"

Can any one suggest where my mistake is in this?

Comment: Thanks @JackyBoy for info. now its 57%. Its fine now?

Comment: I am saying this because people will tend to help you more.

Comment: can you give me answer of my question. its very urgent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the URL your passing in.

Even though you are storing your data in a Folder, that Data is still two things

1. In the documents folder, so it will be syncs
2. The Folder is Associated with your App

To solve this you need to store it in /Library instead of /Documents

So your URL would be

> file:///Users/TEST/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.1/Applications/62854BAB-AB51-4771-895F-28C61983A7AC/**Library**/MyFolder

Storing non sync-able data or just any external data in the Library folder is Apples new preference since iCloud was implemented

Comment: Apple rejected my app if I placed it in the library folder.  If you look at the documentation on it says "Use the Library subdirectories for any files you don’t want exposed to the user. Your app should not use these directories for user data files."  I found that I had to encode my files with  `NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:filename];
    [url setResourceValue: [ NSNumber numberWithBool: YES ] forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: nil ];`

Comment: @justdan0227 At the time I wrote this answer (nearly 3 years ago) that was Apple's preference, if you are storing something that is modified by the user then it should be stored in Documents because typically you want it sync'd between devices. Storing data in the library so it doesn't sync was acceptable at the time I submitted the answer

Answer (score 3):

Code looks fine to me.

Are you sure that all the files/folders are getting the flags set properly.

You can do that by this terminal command ->  ls -al -@