# Obj-C - Adding 'skip-backup' attribute always fails

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, icloud

I cannot seem to get the backup attribute parameter working from my code.  No matter what I seem to do, the method returns false with "Unknown Error -1".  I have tried different iterations of the skip-backup method, but below is the latest I'm using, based on another post I found:

```
- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
    const char* filePath = [[URL path] fileSystemRepresentation];
    const char* attrName = "com.apple.MobileBackup";
    if (&NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey == nil) {
        // iOS 5.0.1 and lower
        u_int8_t attrValue = 1;
        int result = setxattr(filePath, attrName, &attrValue, sizeof(attrValue), 0, 0);
        return result == 0;
    } else {
        // First try and remove the extended attribute if it is present
        int result = getxattr(filePath, attrName, NULL, sizeof(u_int8_t), 0, 0);
        if (result != -1) {
            // The attribute exists, we need to remove it
            int removeResult = removexattr(filePath, attrName, 0);
            if (removeResult == 0) {
                NSLog(@"Removed extended attribute on file %@", URL);
            }
        }

        // Set the new key
        return [URL setResourceValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error:nil];
    }
}
```

My call to the method looks like the following (it always prints "not successful" during runtime):

```
if ([self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]]) {
    NSLog(@"success!");
} else {
    NSLog(@"not successful");
}
```

And the filePath is the NSString path to the documents folder's image.  I logged an example of an image path as follows:

/var/mobile/Applications/B3583D06-38BC-45F0-A027-E79997F0EC60/Documents/myImage.png

In my app, it's looping through all the (numerous) files I push out there, and it's adding this attribute.  It fails on each and every one of them.  I need to be able to get this working, due to a hard requirement of offline capabilities for these dynamically-driven files.  I don't see that many others are having this issue, so that tells me I may be missing something obvious here, lol.

I found this post: [Why was my application still rejected after excluding files from iCloud backup using this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588652/why-was-my-application-still-rejected-after-excluding-files-from-icloud-backup-u)

And that looks promising as to what my issue could be, but there are not really any details about how to specifically resolve (it just recommends to use /Library instead of the docs folder?).

Thanks to anyone in advance who can help with this!
-Vincent

Comment: What is your iOS SDK version and iOS target version?

Comment: Sorry I should've mentioned that.  iOS SDK is: 5.1, iOS target version is: 4.3 (but this can be raised if needed).  My device is on the latest OS, though, and that's where I'm running the app from Xcode.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fix this, I ended up just having to create a folder within the /Documents directory, and then I changed the app to point all the files to that sub-folder.

So in my AppDelegate, before anything has loaded up-front, I added code like the following:

```
NSString *tempDir = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/tempfiles"];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:tempDir
                      withIntermediateDirectories:NO
                                       attributes:nil
                                            error:nil];
NSURL *tempDirPathURL = [NSURL URLWithString:tempDir];
if ([[MainControl controlSystem] addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:tempDirPathURL]) {
        NSLog(@"did add attribute!");
} else {
    NSLog(@"adding attribute failed! :(");
}
```

And when I did that, it actually got into the 'did add attribute' log statement with no issues! I have no idea why this didn't work at the individual file level, but at least this works, and it's actually a better solution, since now I didn't have to loop through hundreds of files to add the attribute, and I only had to add it in one place.