# saving an image file from UIImageView

Tags: ios

I'm trying to save the image from a `UIImageView` as per below:

```
NSString  *pngfile = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Library/file.png"];
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:pngfile atomically:YES];
```

Everything is saving properly. My question is, will there be a problem with Apple saying that this file needs to be marked so it doesn't get backed up? I was reading examples as per this page:

[Why was my application still rejected after excluding files from iCloud backup using this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588652/why-was-my-application-still-rejected-after-excluding-files-from-icloud-backup-u)

And a few other pages. But is this necessary for saving this image in this instance?

Comment: Should the file be backed up? Can it be easily recreated? If the image can't be easily recreated then it should be backed up and Apple shouldn't have a problem. If the image can easily be recreated then put it in the caches directory and deal with the possibility it won't exist at some point.

Answer (score 0):

How big is the average size of image files you saved? I found that saving images using writeToFile normal produce large files (than expected). You may check the file size after storing them.

Comment: File sizes weren't a real issue for me, its a small file. And it can always be recreated easily.