# IOS - My application still rejected after excluding files from iCloud backup

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an application, when I sent Apple review then my app is rejected

> 2.23 Details
>
> On launch and content download, your app stores 9.94 MB on the user's iCloud, which does not comply with the iOS Data Storage Guidelines.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Please verify that only the content that the user creates using your app, e.g., documents, new files, edits, etc. is backed up by iCloud as required by the iOS Data Storage Guidelines. Also, check that any temporary files used by your app are only stored in the /tmp directory; please remember to remove or delete the files stored in this location when it is determined they are no longer needed.
>
> Data that can be recreated but must persist for proper functioning of your app - or because users expect it to be available for offline use - should be marked with the "do not back up" attribute. For NSURL objects, add the NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey attribute to prevent the corresponding file from being backed up. For CFURLRef objects, use the corresponding kCRUFLIsExcludedFromBackupKey attribute.
>
> Resources
>
> To check how much data your app is storing:
>
> ```
> - Install and launch your app
>
> - Go to Settings > iCloud > Storage > Manage Storage
>
> - Select your device
>
> - If necessary, tap "Show all apps"
>
> - Check your app's storage
> ```
>
> For additional information on preventing files from being backed up to iCloud and iTunes, see Technical Q&A 1719: How do I prevent files from being backed up to iCloud and iTunes.
>
> If you have difficulty reproducing a reported issue, please try testing the workflow described in Technical Q&A QA1764: How to reproduce bugs reported against App Store submissions.
>
> If you have code-level questions after utilizing the above resources, you may wish to consult with Apple Developer Technical Support. When the DTS engineer follows up with you, please be ready to provide:
>
> - complete details of your rejection issue(s)
> - screenshots
> - steps to reproduce the issue(s)
> - symbolicated crash logs - if your issue results in a crash log

In my app, I excluded files from iCloud backup using this code:
File AppDelegate.m, I added the following code in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: to exclude all files and directories:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
NSArray *documents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:basePath error:nil];
NSURL *URL;
NSString *completeFilePath;
for (NSString *file in documents) {
    completeFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", basePath, file];
    URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:completeFilePath];
    NSDictionary *values = [URL resourceValuesForKeys:@[NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey] error:nil];
    if ([values[NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey] boolValue] == NO) {
        NSLog(@"To exclude from iCloud backup: %@", completeFilePath);
        [URL setResourceValue:@(YES) forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error:nil];
    }
}
```

Can any one suggest where my mistake is in this? Thanks!

Comment: I haven't run into this, but it may be that you are using the file system on the device incorrectly. Exactly what data is the app installing or storing, and where? Review Apple's [File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) to ensure you're storing your app's data appropriately.

Comment: Also you are passing nil for the error parameter in three places here. Use valid parameters there and test for NSError objects.

Comment: whats your file storage path?

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588652/why-was-my-application-still-rejected-after-excluding-files-from-icloud-backup-u?rq=1